# Injecting IConfiguration into Serilog Setup

Tags: .net, .net-6.0, serilog

I building a console app using .NET 6 with DI by using `Host.CreateDefaultBuilder`.
I'm am also using `Serilog` for logging and I am facing an inconvenience that I would like to solve while setting up `Serilog`

Program.cs

```
IConfiguration configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                              .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json")
                               // .AddUserSecrets<Program>()
                              .Build();

using IHost host =
    Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
        .ConfigureAppConfiguration(builder => builder.AddJsonFile("appsettings.json").AddUserSecrets<Program>())
        .UseSerilog(new LoggerConfiguration().ReadFrom.Configuration(configuration).CreateLogger())
        .ConfigureServices(services =>
         {...})
        .Build();
```

There is code redundancy related to setting up IConfigaration.

Is there a way to use the `configuration` variable inside `ConfigureAppConfiguration()` ? Or is it possible to somehow inject the configuration inside `UseSerilog` so that I don't have to create the `configuration` variable in the first place?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use another overload of the method `.UseSerilog()` that provides you more input.

```
Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
    .UseSerilog(ConfigureLogger);

void ConfigureLogger(HostBuilderContext context, LoggerConfiguration loggerConfiguration)
{
    loggerConfiguration.ReadFrom.Configuration(context.Configuration);
}
```

`ConfigureLogger()` will be called when the Host is being built. At that point in time, Configuration is already created.

Comment: @user19187727, I provided an update with a better answer.